# jQuery: selectors dont work on ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here is a simple script which i want sum1 to debug and report my mistakes.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#content1").click(function() {
                    $("#content2").load("test.php");
                });
                $("span").click(function() {
                    $(this).css("font-size", "30px");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content1">Click to load content2</div>
        <div id="content2"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

--test.php--

```
<span>Click to format content 2&#60;/span><br>
```

now my problem is that the selector for span does not work.

Comment: If someone calls your name before you enter the room, would that person be able to find you? That is what is happening here. You are asking for all the spans before you add the span to the page, how is the selector supposed to find the span before it is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event delegation:

```
$("#content2").on("click", "span", function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("body").on("click","span",function(){
    $(this).css("font-size","30px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the span click function inside the success event of the $("#content2").load function

This way the the new span click bind function is triggered only after the new span is loaded to the page , hence the click event is applied to new span as well.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#content1").click(function() {
                    $("#content2").load("test.php",function(){

                       // Now the click event is assigned after the span is loaded.
                       // Hence its applied to newly loaded span as well
                       $("span").click(function() {
                         $(this).css("font-size", "30px");
                       });

                    });
                });

            });
</script>
```

Cheers..!!